# How do you configure recycle bins on roaming profiles?

Tags: roaming-profile, folder-redirection, windows

I copied the following from a post on the Spiceworks forum which remained unanswered:
Is there any way to place the Recycle Bin back on the desktop of a Roaming Profile with the Desktop being redirected? I have used Google and can't find a straight forward answer. I am asking for people with experience in this. This is for a Windows XP machine. I saw mention of needing to use a program such as Undelete but I'm hoping that is not the case.

Further explanation: I use redirected folders and whenever a user deletes something from their desktop,my documents it doesn't show up in the recycle bin.  It doesn't appear in the recycle bin on the server either.  Where is this data?  I doubt it is permanently deleted.  Is there a way to change the recycle bin on the users' desktop to display those files?

Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

The data is on the network server that served up the shares somewhere. **Or not**, depending on what kind of network resource is holding the files. There are various tricks to enable the actual recycle bin under some circumstances, but I personally have reservations about how reliable this is.

If you're using Windows server 2003 or better, I strongly suggest a better way of doing this is to enable [volume shadow copies](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc757854%28v=ws.10%29.aspx) for user home drive shared areas, as a far more robust method of letting users manage their own data recovery.